# Удалить все положительные числа с помощью лямбда функции. Как правильно ставить условия в лямбда функции?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Дана последовательность чисел.

Как удалите из нее все положительные числа?

Мое решение:

```py
l = [-323, 4677, -234, 12, 35, -71, 4]

func = list(map(lambda x: l.remove(x) if x > 0 else x, l))
```

Answer (score 6):

я бы воспользовался функцией [filter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
res = list(filter(lambda x: x <= 0, l))
```

результат:

```
In [21]: res
Out[21]: [-323, -234, -71]
```

Если нужно получить сумму всех неположительных чисел:

```
res = sum(filter(lambda x: x <= 0, l))
```

Answer (score 3):

Лучше воспользоваться встроенной функцией filter, отсеивающей элементы, не соответствующие переданному предикату:

```py
l = [-323, 4677, -234, 12, 35, -71, 4]
func = list(filter(lambda x: x <= 0, l))
print(func)
```

Вывод:

```
[-323, -234, -71]
```

Comment: @darkdarklord Есть же встроенная функция `sum`